# Ubuntu: VPN kills NAT

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

[Output: Wireless Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24269758/)

Connection is ISP router (DHCP) - eth0 192.168.1.91 - wlan0(NAT/DHCP) 192.168.5.1

I'm using `hostapd` to bring up the AP, `/etc/network/interfaces` to create interface and static IP, `dnsmasq` for DNS and DHCP for wlan0, and NetworkManager takes care of the eth0 and two static DNS entries (for testing).

wlan0 has internet connection until I start the OpenVPN in NetworkManager.

Here are my iptables:

```
    user@server:~$ sudo iptables -S
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -s 192.168.5.0/24 -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Here are some before/after outputs.

Before:

```
    user@server:~$ route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
    192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

After:

```
    user@server:~$ route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         10.119.72.109   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
    10.119.72.1     10.119.72.109   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
    10.119.72.109   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
    192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
    <ISP public IP> 192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

Is my `route` ok but my `iptables` are messed up?  `iptables` good but `route` messed up?  I'm a `soup-sandwich` and it's all messed up?  I was feeling pretty dern accomplished tackling this on my own until I spent several nights banging my head on the wall once I introduced the VPN into the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a transparent VPN for your wifi, right?

The routing table is OK, but iptables needs an update.

Since your policies aren't restrict, you'll be good with this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan+ -o tun+ -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun+ -j MASQUERADE
```

For the refference, check https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4422.html for `MASQUERADE` target, as it is crucial in dealing with NAT.

Comment: Yes, if I understand the meaning of transparent VPN (no user on the wlan needs to know it exists).  So will these iptables also work without the VPN up?  Are you suggesting I replace my current iptable with yours or append yours to mine?

Comment: @orion_134 Exactly, Wlan users will have no idea of VPN. The same aproach I did on my raspi firewall. Replace your rules with mine, and test. Should work with no problems.

Comment: OK, I will test tonight and update if it works. The next project is to configure the iptables to allow wlan0 (192.165.5.x) to access printer on the ISP network (192.168.1.x) while the other traffic is in the VPN. To Be Continued!

Comment: Well...I thought it was answered when it survived a reboot, but I got home from work today and wlan0 has no internet.  Well, sort of.  I can traceroute from my phone to an ip address, but watching tcpdump on wlan0 repeats `udp port 53 unreachable, length 70` for  each DNS inquiry.  What happened?

Comment: Depending have you used any additional rules. If you try to ping from wlan google.com f.e and get no reply, and you can ping IP - then you have DNS issue. With your default accept policy, this shouldn't be a problem in iptables.

Comment: I can see the servers requesting, but it looks like the port is blocked or something?  Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Strange. This morning it is working again. Both times the computer hadn't rebooted.

Comment: You have some issues, not related to your question.

Comment: Hah, I almost took that personally!